# Subtract thermal resistance of material from thermal output of heat source

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, thermal-conductivity

Im trying to work out the heat output of a under floor heating system.

The underfloor heating system has a stated output of 80w/m2 (watt per meter squared). This is for the system installed with no floor finish laid on top.

On top of the underfloor heating system is the floor finish; wooden floor in some rooms and tile in others. For each of the floor finishes they have a stated thermal resistance being : wooden floor : 0.17 W ⁄ m K ; tile : 2.07 W/mK.

How can i work out the heating output of the underfloor heating system once installed with the floor finish on top of it ? eg. that the installed system will provide 55 w/m2 of heating.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. There is insufficient information here to make a calculation. You need to know the temperature difference across the flooring.

Comment: @sammygerbil i would know the max temprature of the underside of the flooring, as there is a probe that keep the limit as 27 degree C. I wouldnt know the surface temperature of the wood when its 27 degrees below until its installed. I thought thats what the W/mK would be able to give me, is that not the case ? If so is there some other data i would need to get. (also thanks very much for explaining out why -1, allot of people would just set -1 and not say anything so i wouldn't know what to add)

Comment: Given the temperature difference and the thickness of the flooring (and the thermal conductivity W/mK) you can find the rate of heat transfer = thermal output of your heating system. The upper surface temperature is your room temperature. Alternatively, given the thermal output of your system you can work out the temperature difference across the flooring. (I assume that heat doesn't escape elsewhere.) But if you don't know the temperature difference or the thermal output then there isn't enough information to calculate either.

Comment: The output (W/m$^{2}$) is the same in both cases. The surface temperature on the top of the floor will be different, and in steady state can be readily derived from (output/thermal resistance)*(flooring thickness). One could question whether the system is truly in steady state, but the calculation will be close enough. Note this does not account for heat going down into the floor, but assumes that the output is for what is going up.

Answer (score 1):

I will make some assumptions:

1) The floor finishes are 1 cm thick.

2) The system that provides the heat will continuously provide 80 W/m$^2$ until the subfloor reaches 27$^0$C.

3) There is good insulation underneath the subfloor, so that heat is not lost downward.

4) The desired room temperature is 21$^0$ C.

Given these assumptions, the concern is that the flooring provides enough insulation that the heat flux through it is less than desired when there is a temperature difference of 6 degrees across it.  According to the data you provided, there should be no problem at all in the tile rooms.  In the case of the rooms with wood floors, it is more marginal.

Rather than define symbols, I will write this equation in words:

Heat flux = (temperature difference) * ( thermal conductivity) / (floor thickness)

(Note that, according to the units in your question, the thermal resistances are actually thermal conductivities.)

For wood, this comes out to 102 W/m$^2$. For tile, it is more than ten times larger.  102 W/m$^2$ is still greater than the requirement of 55 W/m$^2$, but it is good to have a bit of a cushion for unconsidered factors, so it is marginal.  I don't think there will be any problem at all with the tile.

Answer (score 0):

Heat transfer continues as long as a temperature difference is there, so, this is time dependent as resistance only slows heat down, thus if enough time is given the surface temp will equal the source.

Are you insulating under the slab? If not consider 2" soil-contact foam or more as essential to not lose conduction & radiant to ground; here avg soil temp is 43F/6C.

MIT has a free heat-transfer tool to download, "energy2D", if you enter geometry & adjust property values it's a good estimating tool.